# FPTAS for bin packing

Tags: algorithm, approximation

If an algorithm for bin packing has a guarantee of OPT(I)+log^2(OPT(I)), then there is a fully polynomial approximation scheme for this problem.
I have to prove this statement, but I have no idea where to start. I think I have to show that SOL(A)<=(1+epsilon)OPT(I) and that the running time of algorithm A is polynomial in both |I| and 1/epsilon, but how to get that?

Anyone could give me some hints?

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: maybe this [slides](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~neal/2006/cs260/piyush.pdf) are helpful